# Obtaining values from a column using the max function with oracle sql, including duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been trying all day to use the max function on the results from the select query at the bottom. I want to get from the following:

```
ROOM    NURSES_PER_ROOM
RM2     1
RM1     .1666666666666666666666666666666666666667
RM3     1
```

To:

```
ROOM 
RM2      
RM3
```

Where RM2 and RM3 have the highest NURSES_PER_ROOM ratio.

```
create table Nurse
(PIN varchar2(6) not null primary key,
first_name char(16),
last_name char(20));

create table Room
(number_ varchar2(6) not null primary key,
size_ varchar2(6) not null);

create table Allocation
(nurse varchar2(6) not null primary key,
room varchar2(6) not null,
foreign key (nurse) 
    references Nurse(PIN),
foreign key (room) 
    references Room(number_));

insert into nurse(PIN, first_name, last_name)
values ('NU0011', 'Mary', 'Fritz');
insert into nurse(PIN, first_name, last_name)
values ('NU0012', 'Goth', 'Mortimer');
insert into nurse(PIN, first_name, last_name)
values ('NU0013', 'Rosa', 'Lotta');
insert into nurse(PIN, first_name, last_name)
values ('NU0014', 'Josie', 'Josiah');
insert into nurse(PIN, first_name, last_name)
values ('NU0015', 'Ruth', 'Williams');
insert into nurse(PIN, first_name, last_name)
values ('NU0016', 'Paige', 'Wakeham');

insert into room(number_, size_)
values ('RM1', '6');
insert into room(number_, size_)
values ('RM2', '2');
insert into room(number_, size_)
values ('RM3', '3');

insert into allocation(nurse, room)
values ('NU0011', 'RM1');
insert into allocation(nurse, room)
values ('NU0012', 'RM3');
insert into allocation(nurse, room)
values ('NU0013', 'RM3');
insert into allocation(nurse, room)
values ('NU0014', 'RM3');
insert into allocation(nurse, room)
values ('NU0015', 'RM2');
insert into allocation(nurse, room)
values ('NU0016', 'RM2');

select room, (number_nurses/ro.size_) as nurses_per_room from
    (select room, count(nurse) as number_nurses
    from allocation
    group by room), room ro
where ro.number_ = room
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: Trying to do this without `JOIN` operations or the `CASE` statement.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I understood the question:

- `test` CTE calculates number of nurses per room
- it is then used in a subquery to fetch only rooms with highest numbers of nurses

---

```
SQL> with test as
  2    (select a.room,
  3            count(*) / r.size_ nurses_per_room
  4     from allocation a join room r on r.number_ = a.room
  5     group by a.room, r.size_
  6    )
  7  select t.room
  8  from test t
  9  where t.nurses_per_room = (Select max(t1.nurses_per_room) from test t1);

ROOM
------
RM2
RM3

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want all rows where the calculation `number_nurses` has its max value.  If so, use analytic functions:

```
select r.*
from (select ro.number_, count(*) / ro.size_ as number_nurses,
             rank() over (order by count(*) / ro.size_) as seqnum
      from allocation a join
           room r
           on ro.number_ = a.room
      group by ro.number_, ro.size_
     ) r
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Apologies for not mentioning, I'm avoiding analytic functions for the moment and JOIN operations. Trying to do it without first. Appreciate the really quick response, I'm looking for all the rows where the calculation `NURSES_PER_ROOM` has the max value in that column. so prior to using the max function, I have 1, 0.166666 and 1 as the values and looking to return the rows with the values 1 and 1 because they are both the max but just duplicates.

Comment: @Bowcox: what's wrong with using window functions or the JOIN operator?